# Grunt uglify task goes blank/idle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am very new to task-runners in JS and this is my first attempt with GruntJS. In my Gruntfile.js I have kept several tasks like `jshint`, `cssmin` etc. I am able to run them all from command line, but when I run `grunt uglify' there is no response, the cursor goes to another line and remains so for hours. No error message is shown as well.

Below is my relevant code, I have tried various uglify configuration as I saw different users providing a different set of properties

```
//uglify:{
        //    options: {
        //        mangle : {
        //            except : ['jQuery', 'angular']
        //        },
        //        compress: {
        //            drop_console : true
        //        },
        //        banner: '*****Minified file for Pricing Plan*****',
        //        footer: '*********File ends**********',
        //        preserveComments: false
        //    },
        //    my_target:{
        //        options: {
        //            beautify: true,
        //            files: {
        //                'scripts/pp.min.js': ['scripts/pp.js']
        //            }
        //        }
        //    }
        //},
        uglify: {
            options: {
                banner: '*****Minified file for Pricing Plan*****'
            },
            dist: {
                src: 'scripts/pp.js',
                dest: 'scripts/pp.min.js'
            }
        },


grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

grunt.registerTask('uglify', ['uglify']);
```

On command line I am running `grunt uglify`

Can someone suggest whats wrong here and the way to rectify it.

Just if required: Its an Angular1.x.x project

EDIT: I tried installing uglifyJs and ran the `uglifyjs` command. It successfully uglifies and minifies my code. So is there any thing that needs to be done apart from what I have above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when I run `grunt uglify' there is no response, the cursor goes to another line and remains so for hours.

#### The Issue:

I think the issue is related to how you are registering your `uglify` task. This following line of code:

> ```
> grunt.registerTask('uglify', ['uglify']); //<-- Issue is here.
> ```

#### How to fix it:

When creating an [Alias Task](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#alias-tasks) using `grunt.registerTask()` avoid naming the `taskName` the same as any of the items/tasks defined in the `taskList` array.

```js
grunt.registerTask('minify', ['uglify']); //<-- Correct.
```

***NOTE:*** Although in the example code above I have changed the `taskName` to `minify` it can be any valid name you prefer. Just ensure whatever `taskName` you choose does not also exist as one of the items in the `taskList` array.

You now run the revised registered `uglify` task via CLI as follows:

`$ grunt minify`

#### Gruntfile.js

Here is the revised `Gruntfile.js`:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        uglify: {
            options: {
                banner: '/*****Minified file for Pricing Plan*****/'

                // ... <-- Your other options
            },
            dist: {
                src: 'scripts/pp.js',
                dest: 'scripts/pp.min.js'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.registerTask('minify', ['uglify']);
};
```

(***Note***: Also added forward slashes to your banner string to produce a valid JavaScript comment in the resultant file)